# How to Check if File is ASCII or Binary in C++

Tags: c++, file, binary, ascii

So using the system command file we can use file to determine if a file is ASCII Text or "data".  I wanted to know if there is a way to check in code which one it was?  I want to basically throw a corrupt error if the file is 'data'. I am using ifstream for reading the files.  Thanks for any help!

**Duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/277521/how-to-identify-the-file-content-is-in-ascii-or-binary#277538).**

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over the bytes of the file and use `std::isprint` from `<cchar>` to test whether the character is printable. If there are nonprintable characters in the file, chances are it's a binary file. Notice that this only works for legacy encodings (e.g. ASCII mentioned by you), not for Unicode-encoded files.