# Determine if file is binary or text

Tags: mfc, text-files, binaryfiles

Is there a way to determine if a file is a binary or text file using the the [File Management functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364229%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or MFC?

In the [File Management functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364229%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), GetFileType doesn't seem to distinguish between binary and text files. Same with the dwFileAttributes attribute [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365740%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

In MFC, I tried looking at [CFile::GetStatus()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fa0hc0ht%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), but the m_attribute doesn't say anything about whether files are binary or text.

Does anyone know a way to do this using one of these two libraries? Thank you.

(I'd like to know because I am trying to make a function that recursively goes through a directory. I rewrite the text files (using CStdioFile) and replace some words here and there... but it seems to screw up any images I have in the directory. I'd like to be able to copy the images too... but i need a way to distinguish between binary and text files so I can treat them differently.)

Comment: A file is a text  file if its used in a text application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, there's no simple API to do this, MFC or otherwise.  However, there's a bunch of useful ideas in these similar questions:

[How do I distinguish between 'binary' and 'text' files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/567757/how-do-i-distinguish-between-binary-and-text-files)

[How to identify the file content as ASCII or binary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/277521/how-to-identify-the-file-content-is-in-ascii-or-binary)