# Regular Expression if a file is a text file

Tags: regex, jsp, file-upload

I have an uploader in JSP, and through this I can upload several kinds of file. I need to perform a control (I think with regular expression, just a simple check on file extension) where the JSP engine could read the content of the file and understand if the file is an image or plain text file. I can accept only plain text (text or XML) and discard all the other kind of files. Could someone help me or suggest another way to do that?

Comment: consider an answer like this one... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/567757/how-do-i-distinguish-between-binary-and-text-files

Comment: With REGEX, is possible do this control?

Answer (score -1):

As a very basic check you could verify the file extension with something like `\.txt$`, however this doesn't prevent people from uploading different filetypes with a .txt extension. You might be better off by checking the mimetype of the file uploaded, a JSP example can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5096862/jsp-get-mime-type-on-file-upload).