# How to more accurate detect one file is a ruby script file in linux

Tags: ruby, linux, file-type

I know the extname is `rb` is worked.

I know linux `file` command is worked to in some case.

But all not accurate enough to decide a file is a ruby scripts

EDIT:

What I want to do is: more accuretely amount the ruby lines I wrote
with a bash shell scripts like followings:

```
find -name '*.rb' |xargs -n100 cat |grep -v '\s*#' |wc -l
```

but, in fact, I wrote some executable ruby scripts, and others, e.g.
`.rake`, `Gemfile` `Capfile` `jbuider` etc ...

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by *more accurate*? Do you want to ensure that the file actually contains Ruby code or at least is a valid Ruby file?

Comment: @spickermann, linux `file` command, make my so much ruby file recognized as  `ASCII text` or `C++ source, ASCII text`, And `.rb` extension will ignore some special executable file and others. (e.g. .rake)

Answer (score 2):

Use `ruby -c`. From the man page:

> ```
> -c    Causes Ruby to check the syntax of the script and exit
> ```

This will tell you if the file is a valid Ruby script without executing it. If it is, it will print "Syntax OK" to STDOUT and exit with status code 0; otherwise it will print a syntax error to STDERR and exit with a nonzero code. (You can of course suppress the messages using I/O redirection, e.g. `&>/dev/null`.)

Of course, false positives are possible (the fact that a file is *valid* Ruby doesn't necessarily mean it was intended to be a Ruby script), but unlikely except with very short files.

Comment: Cool! this is exactly what I want. though, for some special file, e.g.  git packed object, ruby -c is not worked. e.g.  ╰─ $ ruby -c ./.git/objects/pack/pack-ef0573228b2fa7437e0913240d5cd6e7eca853a9.pack
Syntax OK       , But this not a big deal, I could skip `.git` directory to avoid this.

Comment: @zw963 That's interesting. I would use `ruby -c` in combination with `file` or another technique to [check if it's a binary file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/567757/how-do-i-distinguish-between-binary-and-text-files).

Comment: @Jordon,  yes, I think I need to do like you suggestion too. because ``ruby -c ./app/assets/images/favicon.ico
Syntax OK
``  is a little confusing,  the same case for `ttf` files,  But if in combination with `file+grep` recognized as ` text$`, it worked like a charm

Comment: We need skip `*.js` too,  ```$ cat 1.js
(function () {asdfsadfasdfsdafasdfasdfasdfasdfa}).call(this);

 $ ruby -c 1.js
Syntax OK
```

Comment: Yep. Like I said, there will be false positives.

Comment: Finally I use this answer resolve my problem,  please see gist: https://gist.github.com/927c8d45137353dc68553782d004bfa1

Answer (score 0):

What you want is impossible. For example, the following is a valid, and semantically identical program in at least Ruby, PHP, Scala, and Perl:

```
print("Hello");
```

It is also valid in Python, although semantically slightly different: it prints a newline (i.e. it prints the string `"Hello\n"`) while the others don't (the others print `"Hello"` without a newline).

It is also at least syntactically valid in ECMAScript, and may be semantically equivalent assuming a suitable `print` function exists in the standard library.

It is probably valid in a lot more languages than that, some that I can think of are AmbientTalk, Atomy, CoffeeScript, Converge, Dart, Dylan, E, Elixir, Falcon, Fancy, Groovy, Hack, Io, Ioke, Julia, Lua, Monte, Neko, Pico, Pike, and Seph. It is also a valid fragment, although not a complete program, in at least Perl6, C, C++, Objective-C, Objective-C++, D, Java, C♯, Spec♯, Sing♯, M♯, Cω, X♯, Kotlin, Ceylon, Rust, and Rust.

There is no way of knowing whether this is a Ruby program except asking the person who wrote it.

Comment: If we could add a special comment, which told `file` or others tools, this is a ruby scripts, it maybe help a lot. though, I don't know if this exist.