# How to get encoding when I read a .csv File?

Tags: c#, silverlight, encoding, csv, openfiledialog

As title, the following code...

```
System.IO.FileInfo _fInfo;
OpenFileDialog openDlg = new OpenFileDialog();
openDlg.Filter = "Csv Files (.csv)|*.csv";
openDlg.FilterIndex = 1;
openDlg.Multiselect = false;
bool? userClickedOK = openDlg.ShowDialog();

if (userClickedOK == true)
{
    _fInfo = openDlg.File;
}
Stream fileStream = _fInfo.OpenRead();
using (System.IO.StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(fileStream))
{
    int lineNo = 1;
    while (!reader.EndOfStream)
    {
       reader.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Is any way to find "_fInfo" current encoding?
PS: I used silverlight console(silverlight 2.0).

Comment: A simple google search for `get file encoding c#` would return many a code samples.

Comment: Take a look at this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/90838/how-can-i-detect-the-encoding-codepage-of-a-text-file

Comment: Try this also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1347088/c-is-there-any-way-to-discover-what-charset-encoding-a-file-is-using

Comment: @ColeTobin Funny, I did just that and ended up on this question of StackOverflow where the first comment tells me to "google it". Nice.

Answer (score 0):

Try StreamReader.CurrentEncoding after first read. The reader will try to detect encoding.