# How to Check whether a file is text file or not in ASP

Tags: file-io, asp-classic

How to Check whether a file is text file or not in ASP

Comment: With great difficulty; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/277521/how-to-identify-the-file-content-is-in-ascii-or-binary

Comment: do you want to know if the uploaded file is has txt extenstion? if so, what is the uploader you are using"?

Comment: <%
dim fs
set fs=Server.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Response.Write(fs.GetExtensionName("c:\test\test.htm"))
set fs=nothing
%>

Output:

htm

Answer (score 0):

```
<%
dim fs
set fs=Server.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Response.Write(fs.GetExtensionName("c:\test\test.htm"))
set fs=nothing
%>

Output:

htm
```