# How can I detect if a file is binary (non-text) in dart?

Tags: dart, binaryfiles

In a dart console application, how can I tell if a file is binary (non-text)?

Answer (score 2):

Read the file content and check if you find non-displayable characters. An example would be `\u0000` or consecutive `\u0000`, which often occurs in binary files but not in text files.

See also [How can I determine if a file is binary or text in c#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/910873), https://stackoverflow.com/a/277568/217408

Answer (score 1):

I use this code to define a binary or text file:

```
bool isBinary(String path) {
  final file = File(path);
  RandomAccessFile raf = file.openSync(mode: FileMode.read);
  Uint8List data = raf.readSync(124);
  for (final b in data) {
    if (b >= 0x00 && b <= 0x08) {
      raf.close();
      return true;
    }
  }
  raf.close();
  return false;
}

try {
  isBinary('/filepath.ext');
} on FileSystemException {}
```